# Variable in External JS Not Found -- Order is correct

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having an issue where a variable defined in the 1st JS (loaded first) isn't recognized in a later imported JS.

First of all, order of loading (**verified in the debugger: #1 loads first**):

```
<!-- Scheduler JS, #1 -->
<script src="codyhouse-schedule-template/js/scheduler.js"></script>
<!-- Custom JS, #2 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
```

**scheduler.js** has the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // some functions, we skip those...

    var schedules = $('.cd-schedule');
    var objSchedulesPlan = [],
        windowResize = false;    
});
```

**app.js** has the following

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   // some functions, we skip those...

    alert('objSchedulesPlan = ' + objSchedulesPlan);
});
```

Error
    objSchedulesPlan is not defined

Firebug shows that on Document Ready, `scheduler.JS` goes first, and defines those vars; then `app.JS` goes second, and can't find these vars. Am I missing something?

Comment: because it's not defined globally! Put `var objSchedulesPlan = []` outside of the jquery ready function

Comment: But I thought all document-onReady's get combined? Or you mean a var has to be defined outside the jQuery(document).ready(function(..) ?

Comment: Exactly, it has to be defined outside of it.

Comment: This article may help: [What You Should Already Know about JavaScript Scope](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/10/20/javascript-scope-closures/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

objSchedulesPlan is a local variable. Declare it globally.

```
var objSchedulesPlan;

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // some functions, we skip those...

    var schedules = $('.cd-schedule');

    objSchedulesPlan = [],
        windowResize = false;    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Define your variable outside the `$(document).ready` to be global defined. Each `$(document).ready` is limited to its own space

```
var objSchedulesPlan
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        var schedules = $('.cd-schedule');
        objSchedulesPlan = [],
        windowResize = false;    
    });
```